YAML passed as a variable in dbt command in airflow/shell script
I have a problem with YAML validation. A dictionary value contains space and it causes a problem. My error message in airflow looks like this:
Executing following command:
dbt run --vars {"post_hook":"reset query_group","whatever":"else"}   
[0m12:28:39  The YAML provided in the --vars argument is not valid.

Error: Invalid value for '--vars': String '{"post_hook":"reset' is not valid YAML

Actually when I run this in my command line (git bash) it works without errors. It's only a problem when run on airflow.
How can I escape this?
I tried single quote like this:
dbt run --vars '{"post_hook":"reset query_group","whatever":"else"}'

I tried double quote as well:
dbt run --vars "{post_hook:'reset query_group',run_elementary:True}"


EDIT: See this partial answer for further investigation into this issue.
tl;dr: The DBT command is passed as a string argument to a shell script.

´{ ... , ... }means _brace expansion_. You can verify this by turning tracing on usingset -x`.

BTW, your question would be easier to read, if you would format your code properly.

Supposing that you are executing these commands in Bash or another Bourne-family shell, the single-quote variation presented should do the right thing for passing the YAML through to dbt.  If you find otherwise, then that probably reflects a flaw in dbt.  The double-quote variation too, for that matter, but I prefer the former.

If you are not executing them in Bash, or at least in another Bourne-family shell, then this question is incorrectly tagged.  I'm uncertain how Airflow affects that.

Try this: --vars "{'post_hook':['reset query_group'],'run_elementary':True}"

Have you found a solution? We're getting the same issue trying to run DBT in a GitHub Action/workflow (even though it works fine locally). We even tried with --vars "key: value", but still no luck.

Just found a very poor workaround... but hopefully someones knows a better way to make this work.

Just found a solution! And I added it to my answer below.

Asking people to click on links to find more information about your question so they can help you will greatly reduce the pool of people willing/able to help you. Just include all relevant information in your question so it';s as easy as possible for as many people as possible to help you.

You can use eval for this case :
Airflow script.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "\$1 : $1"
eval "$1"

test with :
./script.sh "dbt run --vars '{\"post_hook\":\"reset query_group\",\"whatever\":\"else\"}'"

If you have the possibility to pass multiple strings to Airflow script, then you can avoid the use of eval by defining Airflow script2.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo "\$@ : $@"
"$@"

test with :
./script2.sh dbt run --vars '{"post_hook":"reset query_group","whatever":"else"}'


This is it! And it even works like this (without all the extra quotes): ./script2.sh dbt run --vars '{post_hook: reset query_group, whatever: else}'

tl;dr: Solution is at the bottom: dbt run --vars {'key':'value','key2':'value2'}

We found a very poor way to make it work by separating the vars from the command variable.
In our workflow/GitHub action (I assume Airflow is also doing something similar), the DBT command is passed as a string to a Docker container, which then executes the command like this (in an entrypoint.sh script):
$1 2>&1 | tee logs.txt

When --vars is specified as part of the command, we get the same error as OP, no matter what we try (maybe we're missing some magic trick).
So instead, we've been able to make it work by hardcoding the vars in the Docker container executable (which is obviously far from ideal):
$1 --vars '{key: value}' 2>&1 | tee logs.txt

I'm pretty sure a bash/shell guru would know how to fix this properly, so I'll try setting a bounty on this question.

UPDATE: I've actually been able to simplify the issue and make it reproducible locally using a simple script:
script.sh:
#!/bin/bash
echo $1
$1

And then call ./script.sh "dbt run --vars '{key: value}'"
I really don't see how that is any different than calling the command directly (which works)... ‍♂️ But a bash scripting guru would probably know.

UPDATE 2: We finally managed to get it to work! Although I have no idea why or how it works this way (or why it didn't work any other way)... so I'd still love to hear an explanation!
This did the trick: ./script.sh "dbt run --vars {'key':'value','key2':'value2'}"
And this also works: ./script.sh "dbt run --vars ""{'key':'value','key2':'value2'}"""
Which ironically does not work when called from outside of the context of a script (i.e. dbt run --vars {'key':'value','key2':'value2'}). In that case, quotes are required around the vars: dbt run --vars "{'key':'value','key2':'value2'}"

I wish you'd just asked a new question. This is now confusing with different people chiming in with different examples and parts of the question in the question vs in this answer plus you said "Just found a solution!" so it's not even clear if there's a still a question to be answered and, if there is, if it's the same question that was originally asked or something different.

I'm not familiar with dbt nor do I have it to test with but whatever it is you're trying to do, just from a shell programming perspective, leaving $1 unquoted is not the way to do it. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes and https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 (in particular https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time in that FAQ) can probably help you.

"dbt run --vars ""{'key':'value','key2':'value2'}""" is identical to "dbt run --vars {'key':'value','key2':'value2'}" as it's just the 3 strings 1) "dbt run --vars ", 2) "{'key':'value','key2':'value2'}", and 3) "" concatenated so it's not a surprise that they'd be treated the same way by your script as it doesn't see any difference in them, the shell already concatenated the 3 strings from the first version to be the same single string as the second version before calling ./script.sh.
